# Grafana - Number of requests exceeds SLA

Tags: grafana, graphite, jstatd

I would like to have a bar chart in Grafana with number of requests exceeds SLA. Is there a function or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to connect to the database that stores the number of requests. To do this you'll have to have a datasource plugin that provides the connectivity within Grafana. There are a number of 'out of the box' [data source plugins available](https://grafana.com/plugins?type=datasource) with Grafana.

If your database isn't listed there you'll need to create your own data source plugin, following the instructions [here](http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/datasources/). It's important to note that to create your own plugins you need to be able to code in either JavaScript or a language that compiles to JavaScript such as TypeScript.

Once you have your data source plugin connecting to you database it should be rather trivial to get a bar chart on screen using the Graph panel.

Comment: I'm using grahite as the source of the grafana. Is there a particular query that I can use to put up the graph?